# How does one test if a program/executable is present on a system in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have a script that requires openssl be installed on the system.  I want to do a check to see if it is installed.  I've considered using `test-path` but because this script will be on many computers, there's no way of knowing where the user installed openssl or if it is in the system path.

Is there a way to do something like `test-command openssl` (I know that doesn't exist) and get an error level or the like to return in powershell?

Many thanks!

Comment: You could make some educated guesses about common locations, but frankly, the usual approach is to require the user to add the path to the executable to the PATH environment variable (or place the executable in a directory that's already in the PATH). Because otherwise you'd have to traverse all filesystems on the computer, which would take a looooooong time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Use the [`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command) cmdlet** to *explicitly* test if executables can be called by their name only (implying that they're in one of the directories listed in `$env:PATH`) and **for command discovery in general**:

```
$found = [bool] (Get-Command -ErrorAction Ignore -Type Application openssl)

Write-Verbose -vb "openssl.exe found? $found"
```

Casting to `[bool]` evaluates to `$true` only if `Get-Command` returns output, which it only does if the executable is found.

`-Type Application` ensures that only *external programs* are considered; by default, `Get-Command` finds commands of *all* types, including `*.ps1` scripts, cmdlets, functions, and aliases.

The `Get-Command` by itself would also allow you to find out the executable's *full path*, via the output object's `.Source` property.

---

Alternatively, if all that matters is whether the executable is *available*, you can simply *try* to execute your *actual command* and handle an error indicating that the executable is not available via `try` / `catch`:

```
try {
  openssl ... # your *actual* command, not a test
} catch [System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException] {
  # Handle the error, reflected in $_
  Write-Warning $_
  # ... 
}
```

Note that you don't strictly need to catch `[System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException]` specifically, if you're confident that the only error that can occur is due to a missing executable, but note that you could then get potential false positives from errors that occur during evaluation of expression-based arguments, such as attempting to pass `(1 / 0)` as an argument.

Also note that attempting to *test the availability of* an executable by invoking it *without arguments* inside a `try` / `catch` statement is *not* a viable approach, because the executable may enter an interactive shell (as is the case with `openssl`) or produce undesired side effects.

Answer (score 2):

You can use try/catch blocks to do something like the following:

```
$OpenSSLMissing = $false
try {openssl} catch {$OpenSSLMissing = $true}
if ($OpenSSLMissing)
{
    # Do something
}
else
{
    # Do something else
}
```

Comment: Attempting to _test the availability of_ an executable by invoking it _without arguments_ inside a `try` / `catch` statement is _not_ a viable approach, because the executable may enter an interactive shell (as is the case with `openssl`) or produce undesired side effects. However, you could use `try` / `catch` to attempt the _actual invocation_.